# n-D complex and 2n-D real vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is the difference between n dimensional complex vector space and 2n dimensional real vector space?

I know that in the complex vector space, you can define a complex conjugate. (This makes it a dual vector space, right?) But it doesn't seecm that hard to just invert half of the coordinates in the 2n dimensional real vector space and get the same result.

Is there any difference beyond that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

1. A vector from $\mathbb{C}^n$ can be multiplied by a scalar from $\mathbb{C}$. A vector from $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ can not.
2. In $\mathbb{C}^n$ every linear operator has an upper triangular Jordan normal form. In $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ there exist linear operators, that do not have it.
3. The ring of linear operators over $\mathbb{C}^n$ is isomorphic to the ring of $n\times n$ complex matrices and the ring of linear operators over $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is isomorphic to the ring of $2n\times 2n$ real matrices. It is not hard to show, that those two rings are not isomorphic.

If you look more carefully, you can find much more differences between those $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. That is the result of them being two vector spaces over non-isomorphic fields.

Answer (score 2):

We can restrict and define the multiplication between the x and y dimensions to give an isometric field to the complexes but in general this multiplication (and division) is not well defined.